# "Spyder" Undo "Remove all Variables"

Tags: python, spyder

I am using the Variable explorer in Spyder and clicked the "Remove all Variables" button, How do I undo this and restore all variables.

Regards

Comment: did < Ctrl+Z >  worked?

Comment: No sorry it didn't bring the variables back. I tried %reset and that also failed

Comment: probably, run your code again? or go through history of computation. Variable explorer is better used as monitoring tool, I personally do not use it in workflow at all, even though like Spyder veru much

Comment: Hi. I tried running the code again but the variables didn't return. I am using it to just check that I am manipulating the np arrays that I am using in the right way

Comment: Well, if you started with the same inputs and ran the same code you ought to get the same outputs, unless there's any randomness involved, or dependence on external data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no undo for that operation. *Remove all variables* is equivalent to running `del my_var` for all variables present in the IPython console.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found it useful.

Comment: By any means is it possible to bring these variable back? I tried re-installing Anaconda and Spyder but doesn't help.

Comment: As I clearly said above, that's not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system and Spyder should be able to set up the user variables for you to run python scripts again. I did do "Remove all variables" and then restarted my system. In my case, I didn't loose anything significant. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Re-running your code should make all variables reappear in the variable explorer. That being said, I experienced the same issue: none of my variables would show up when I re-ran the code. In my case I had to remove my variables from the functions and use them separately. Then they loaded into the variable explorer.